# UIAlertView with buttons vertically stacked and an X to close

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uialertview

I got this image in a mockup for me to follow and I'm wondering if there is a way to make a `UIAlertView` that looks like the alert view shown below.

[image]

Comment: Only on iOS 7, I suppose. But it's still under NDA.

Comment: Well, this is iOS7 alertview, based on flat UI. And yes you can add a subview on top of alertview, so a cross at the top right is not a problem.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to change the view hierarchy of an UIAlertView, check the documentation to be sure, if you do your app could be rejected from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow you to change an UIAlertView , if you want to mimic the effect then you have to create the UI and add it to the view of the view controller, the window, or the view of the navigation controller. Then you will need to implement the methods for each button and the "X" button as well.